# How to make tensor flow print full traceback

Tags: python, tensorflow, traceback, tqdm

I am getting an exception in tensorflow , it doesn't stop the program but pops up in te output and things are broken after the exception. but the trace back doesn't really follow the problem back to a useful point that i can fix. just some vague index error.

below is my script

```
def make_model(layers , model_type):

    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

    convnet = input_data(shape=[None,STANDARDIZED_IMAGE_SIZE,STANDARDIZED_IMAGE_SIZE, 1], name='input')
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation='relu')
    convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
    convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
    convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 2, activation='softmax')
    convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
    model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir=actual_dir, tensorboard_verbose=3)
    model.save(actual_dir+"/"+MODEL_NAME)
    return model


def find_model_accuracy(model , test_features, test_labels):
    test_results = {}
    test_results['model'] = model.evaluate(test_features, test_labels)
    print(f" Accuracy: {test_results}")

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,STANDARDIZED_IMAGE_SIZE,STANDARDIZED_IMAGE_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,STANDARDIZED_IMAGE_SIZE,STANDARDIZED_IMAGE_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]




model_1 = make_model(layers , 1)
print(" model made ")
model_1.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y},validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),  n_epoch=1 , snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
print(" model trained ")
acc1 = find_model_accuracy(model_1 , test_y, test_x)

print("-------------------------------------")
print(X.ndim)
print(X.shape)
print("-------------------------------------")
print(test_x.ndim)
print(test_x.shape)
print("-------------------------------------")
```

which produces this output.

```
Training Step: 12  | total loss: 0.62046 | time: 22.450s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.62046 - acc: 0.6685 -- iter: 768/830
Training Step: 13  | total loss: 0.65215 | time: 25.264s
| Adam | epoch: 001 | loss: 0.65215 - acc: 0.6431 | val_loss: 0.62987 - val_acc: 0.6058 -- iter: 830/830
--
Exception in thread Thread-20:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 197, in slice_array
    return [x[start] for x in X]
  File "C:\Users\tgmjack\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 197, in <listcomp>
    return [x[start] for x in X]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
 model trained 
 Accuracy: {'model': [0.0]}
-------------------------------------
4
(830, 150, 150, 1)
-------------------------------------
4
(208, 150, 150, 1)
-------------------------------------
```

The reasons im saying its broken after the exception, is it achieves an accuracy of around ~0.6 when fitting but 0 afterwards, when evaluating.

How could i print the full traceback from the index error during fitting

ps)

I am using tensorflow 2.9.1, on a jupyter notebook.

My data is well shuffled each time so its not just a bad slice of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the full stack trace, calling [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging/disable_traceback_filtering) command should do the trick:

```
tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()
```

For re-activating the filtering back:

```
tf.debugging.enable_traceback_filtering()
```

About the error, you are somewhere indexing a numpy array with an index 2. But the array on the first dimension has size 2 (so only index 0 and 1 are accepted).

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/debugging) you can find other useful info for debugging in tensorflow.

Comment: hmmm, it doesnt seem to change a thing. i wonder if my assumption that there should be a longer traceback to something i did is wrong.

Comment: If you need help resolving the issue you can modify your question, making the problem reproducible: adding the imports and all the data needed to execute the code. This way I can try to find out what the problem is